Family of integrals of Riemann integrable functions
I am examining the following family of functions:
$$\mathcal{F}=\{ F(x) =\int_0^{x} f(t)dt \mid x\in [0,1], f\in \mathcal{R}([0,1]) \hbox{ and }||f||_{\infty}\le B\}.$$
Where $B$ is a fixed positive number and $\mathcal{R}([0,1])$ is the set of Riemann integrable function on $[0,1]$, and $||\cdot||_\infty$ is the supremum norm, i.e $||f||_\infty= \sup_{[0,1]}(f(x))$.
I’ve already shown that $\mathcal{F}$ is a subset of the set of continuous functions on $[0,1]$, $\mathcal{F}$ is pointwise bounded and equicountinous, and so by Arzela Ascoli, the closure of $\mathcal{F}$ is compact, but I am not sure if $\mathcal{F}$ itself is compact.
I don’t have a good idea of how a proof would work, so I’m guessing that $\mathcal{F}$ is not compact.
I understand a counterexample would involve a sequence of $F_n\in \mathcal{F}$ uniformly converging to a $G\not\in \mathcal{F}$ but have not been able to find one.
Am I desperately looking for a non-existent counterexample?

A counter-example would be any sequence in $\cal F$ which does not have a subsequence converging in $\cal F$. There is no need for this sequence to converge, uniformly or otherwise, to anything. I suggest considering Lesbegue integrable functions that are not Riemann integrable.

@Paul But it’s the family of $F$’s, not $f$’s. Perhaps I am not interpreting your hint appropriately.

@TedShifrin - If the Riemann integrable $f_n$ converge to a non-Riemann integrable $f$ Then the limit of their integrals does not converge to a point in $\cal F$. The reference to Legbegue integrable functions was intended to point a possible way of showing the existence of such a sequence.

@PaulSinclair If you have an answer, wouldn’t it be appropriate to provide one as such? I was told to look at a fat cantor set for a counter example if that can help make it more concrete.
